# Can I use $ref in JSON Schema to refer to object from another object?

Tags: python, json, schema, data-modeling, jsonschema

In this example schema below I basically want to require the `reporting_person` in the `incident` object is a `person` object referenced in the `people` array. Is this possible?

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "definitions": {
      "person": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "person_id": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "first_name": {
            "type": "string"
  
          }
        }
      },
      "incident": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "incident_id": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "description": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "reporting_person": {
            "type": "string",
            "$ref": "#/people/person_id"
          }
      }}
    },
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "root" :{
            "type" : "object",
            "properties": {
                "people" : {
                    "type" :"array",
                    "items" : { "$ref": "#/definitions/person"}
                },
                "incidents" : {
                    "type" : "array",
                    "items": {"$ref": "#/definitions/incident"}
                }
              }
            }
        }
  }
```

My other alternative is just to define an ID standard using patterns and move the confirming to application code but it would be a shame to not do this sort data validity confirmation in the schema. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$ref` to refer to any schema anywhere. In this case, your `$ref` should be `"#/definitions/person/properties/person_id`. However, it's usually cleaner to create a definition for "person_id" and reference that instead of pointing to a property.

I also notice that you have a `"type": "string` next to that `$ref`. That `type` is going to be ignored. If there is a `$ref` in that object, the object will be treated as a reference, not a schema. Therefore, "type" is not evaluated as the `type` keyword. It's just noise inside a reference.